# Download source of page on https from command line

Tags: windows, command-line, wget

Is there a command-line tool which would let me browse to a site (on https) and download the output of the page (its source)?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try out [w3m](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/). You may have to install it via [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) to get it running in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

[Curl](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) can download HTTPS pages.

> curl is a command line tool for transferring data with URL syntax, supporting DICT, FILE, FTP, FTPS, Gopher, HTTP, HTTPS, IMAP, IMAPS, LDAP, LDAPS, POP3, POP3S, RTMP, RTSP, SCP, SFTP, SMTP, SMTPS, Telnet and TFTP. curl supports SSL certificates, HTTP POST, HTTP PUT, FTP uploading, HTTP form based upload, proxies, cookies, user+password authentication (Basic, Digest, NTLM, Negotiate, kerberos...), file transfer resume, proxy tunneling and a busload of other useful tricks.

Answer (score 0):

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://whatever.example.com/somepage.html
```

If you don't have whatever.example.com's SSL signer in your trust store, the `--no-check-certficate` flag keeps it from erroring out.